# Can't load Application Launcher in Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu

Here is the error I am getting when I click on the Application Launcher:

`Error loading QML file: 
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/Kickoff.qml:31:1: module "org.kde.plasma.private.kicker" is not installed`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I typed "plasmashell" in the Konsole and it came back. However, it isn't auto loading on start up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to resolve this issue:

```
sudo apt install kwin-x11
```

Then reboot the system:
    sudo reboot

If that still doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt install sddm xserver-xorg
```

Then reboot.